# DirectX / Media Foundation IMFMediaEngine::SetVolume volume cutoff

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, ms-media-foundation

I came across something interesting. While playing an mp3 file with `IMFMediaEngine` I noticed that the volume controls are not consistent.

This plays the mp3 at 100% volume:

```
float volume_level=1.0f;
m_mediaEngine->SetVolume(volume_level);
```

This plays the mp3 at what seems to be 0% volume (I can't hear anything at 0.4f, only at higher values):

```
float volume_level=0.4f;
m_mediaEngine->SetVolume(volume_level);
```

How does the volume actually work? It doesn't seem to be linear. I also use XAudio2 with DirectX and it appears the 0.0f-1.0f scaling works fine there.

Why can't you hear anything @ 0.4f, it's supposed to be 40% of the volume, not 0%. It's almost as if the volume range is at 0.4f-1.0f

Comment: I suppose the confuse is because subjective perception scale does not match amplitude scale. Where you expected 40% to be something like -40 dB, it instead is a factor of 0.4 on the PCM value.